# Rails Gem installs but doesn't install commands (package?) - Rubber Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, rubygems

I'm trying to install the rubber gem to deploy my application to Amazon EC2. Rubber installs perfectly, but when I run rubber -h to see the installed commands, I only get config. Here's a print screen to demonstrate:

[image]

I've wasted about three days on this so really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably way too late, but I've had the same problem and I bypassed it by manually installing the Capistrano gem in console by typing the following.

```
gem install capistrano
```

and I was able to move onto the next step. Hope this helped.

Comment: Pretty sure I tried this and it had the same result as running bundle. Switching to Linux worked for me, maybe it's not Windows compatible.

Comment: That's what I figured too because after I got through the error I began encountering other errors. I was looking for solutions on forums and I read the developer's post that says Windows users need a lot of configurations to use the gem properly ("you're probably the only one using it on Windows").